# Random select preventing some duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

From Table

```
Name GroupID 
a      Null
b       1
c       1
d       2
e      Null
f      Null
g       3
```

Result expected from random top 4 selection

```
Name GruopID
a  Null
b   1
e  Null
g   3
```

Resuming I want to get random names but only 1 kind of groupid if groupid is <> null
The select Newid() type returns
"Select Top(4) * FROM Table Order By NEWID()"

```
Name GruopID
a  Null
b   1
e  Null
c   1
```

I don´t want that. Hope i made my self clear!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're looking for the [DISTINCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) clause

Comment: could you show your existing query

Comment: What's the query you are using now?

Comment: @Brad - DISTINCT clause will eliminate the rows with null values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (on SQL Server 2005+).

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY NEWID()) Corr
    FROM YourTable
)

SELECT TOP 4 Name, GroupId
FROM CTE
WHERE GroupId IS NULL OR Corr = 1
ORDER BY NEWID()
```